# coverting the string to json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to display my data in json format. Firstly i tried JSON.stringify
then it shows in string format so, then again I tried JSON.parse where I get like array of object finally I tried keeping [0] to the parse object it throws 'undefined'...

can you please tell me where I am doing wrong..

I provide the output of the following console.log..

```
try{
var timekeep =  await Orders.findAndCountAll(
    {         
        where : {
            cid : orders_info.cid,
        },      
        order: [
           ['id', 'DESC']
      ],
      limit: 1,
    }
);
 console.log("RESULT => ", timekeep); 

 var datjsn =  JSON.stringify(timekeep);
 var jsonsr = JSON.parse(datjsn);
 var data23 = jsonsr[0];

 console.log('alpha1'+ datjsn);
 console.log('delta2'+ jsonsr);
 console.log('beta'+ data23);  


output of the console logs
RESULT =>  { count: 1,
rows:
[ orders {
   dataValues: [Object],
   _previousDataValues: [Object],
   _changed: {},
   _modelOptions: [Object],
   _options: [Object],
   __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
   isNewRecord: false } ] }

 alpha1 {"count":1,"rows":[ {"id":4006,"mid":1,"cid":41,"wid":7138,"oid":null,"status":null,"options":null,"starttime":"2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z","duration":null,"ordertotal":50,"counter":null,"closetime":null}]}
 delta2 [object  Object]

 beta undefined
```

Comment: try `jsonsr.rows[0]`

Comment: what do you want in beta? it's not an array, so you can't use jsonsr[0] directly. Do you want count or rows ? or something inside rows?

Comment: yeah I need data inside rows.. meanwhile I want count number also.

Answer (score 0):

var data23 = jsonsr[0];

In here you have took wrong place. Actually the data is in `jsonsr.rows[0].`

For this you can use,

```
jsonsr.rows[0];
```

or if the key value is not known use the `Object.keys` to get the all the objects in array and `proceeding with loop` with the condition of check the object value in `array and length greater than 0` can get the all the datas.

Comment: so I added like this  var data23 = jsonsr.rows[0];

Comment: Yes because the data is in array of objects. To console those you must change the result to string.

Answer (score 0):

The object is sequelize object not just object.
Try to use `.get()`

```
var timekeep =  await Orders.findAndCountAll(
    {         
        where : {
            cid : orders_info.cid,
        },      
        order: [
           ['id', 'DESC']
      ],
      limit: 1,
    }
);

console.log(timekeep.rows[0].get())
```